# Chrome back button redirects to wrong site

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

So I am using NodeJs and I use the following function to request content from the server which I want to display in the browser.
The server returns a complete html page.

When I take the following steps, chrome skips the original page which calles the redirect code.

1. I call my website from a new tab in chrome
2. The code gets executed
3. I get redirected to a page with the response content of the server (using *var win = ...*) or the current document is overwritten (using *document.open(); ...*)
4. Problem: If I use the back button now, Chrome navigates me to the "new tab" page and not my page from which I got redirected.

Using Firefox this problem does not occur.

I read that this is an old problem with chrome but are there some workarounds?

Code:

```
function requestLink(id) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:1234/link", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  xhr.onload = function () {
      if (this.status == 200) {
          // possibility 1:
          // document.open();
          // document.write(this.response);
          // document.close();

          // possibility 2:
          var win = window.open("", "_self");
          win.document.write(this.response);
      }
  };
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify({requested: id}));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour I guess.

To manipulate your browser history, check out this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

This only works in newer browsers...

Comment: I tumbled across this solution too but what do I use instead of _stateObj_?
document or JSON.stringify(document.body) do not work.
**EDIT** In my function _requestLink_ I want to add the current page to the history. That should do it right?

Comment: This can be an empty object and defines the page's state. (so you can add extra data there do define what's happening on your page). The most important param for you is the third one: "bar.html", which is the url that should be pushed into the history.